# dynamic layout changing with priority

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create a layout with 5 gridviews(GV1,GV2,GV3,GV4,GV5). gridviews has priority 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. Based on the size of arraylist passed to adapter, the weight of gridview is calculated

**weight = size * priority**

Now weight will decide the amount of area that will be occupied by that particular gridview in layout.
I have attached the code below. but it doesnt work.

```
   RelativeLayout rl =new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    GridView burger_GV = new GridView(this);
    burger_GV.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (burgerAL.size()*BURGER_PRIORITY)));
    burger_GV.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

    GridView pizza_GV = new GridView(this);
    pizza_GV.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (pizzaAL.size()*PIZZA_PRIORITY)));
    pizza_GV.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    GridView sides_GV = new GridView(this);
    sides_GV.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (sidesAL.size()*SIDES_PRIORITY)));
    sides_GV.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);


    GridView cookies_GV = new GridView(this);
    cookies_GV.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (cookiesAL.size()*COOKIES_PRIORITY)));


    GridView beverages_GV = new GridView(this);
    beverages_GV.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (beveragesAL.size()*BEVERAGES_PRIORITY)));


    burger_GV.setAdapter(new BurgerAdapter(burgerAL));
    pizza_GV.setAdapter(new BurgerAdapter(pizzaAL));
    sides_GV.setAdapter(new BurgerAdapter(sidesAL));
    cookies_GV.setAdapter(new BurgerAdapter(cookiesAL));
    beverages_GV.setAdapter(new BurgerAdapter(beveragesAL));

    rl.addView(burger_GV);
    rl.addView(pizza_GV);
    rl.addView(sides_GV);
    rl.addView(cookies_GV);
    rl.addView(beverages_GV);

    setContentView(rl,param);
```

Can anyone suggest me the solution or any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `GridView.LayoutParams` for all your `GridView`

```
GV.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(0, 
            0, (burgerAL.size()*COOKIES_PRIORITY)));
```

It doesn't work because you are using WRAP_CONTENT as the height and width. The weight is used to distribute the remaining empty space or take away space when the total sum is larger than the LinearLayout. Set your widths to 0dip instead and it will work.
Also `RelativeLayout` does not pay attention to `android:layout_weight`. (That's a property of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but not of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`)

Comment: LinearLayout will arrange all the GV either in horizontal or vertical orientation.but I want GV's to be arranged in random on layout...I am unable to show the image as i dont have reputation to load image.

Comment: I tried the solution but it doesn't work. I leaves the screen blank.

Comment: Upload your images on some web site and post it. I don't understand what you have, and what you want :)

Comment: on which website can i host?